# Cannot detect partitions during Ubuntu 18.04 install (dualboot with Windows 10)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 18.04, raid, bios

I attempting to install Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10; I am using a Dell XPS 15 9560. First, I made sure to put the boot in Legacy mode with secure boot turned off, as it was initially in UEFI mode. When I booted into Ubuntu 18.04 with my USB to install it, there was a strange error when it asks for the installation type. Instead of the usual screen where it asks whether to erase all other data or install alongside windows, shows advanced partition options, etc. it shows this: [image] 
It appears to be looking for partitions in /dev/sda, but all my main partitions are present in /dev/sdb. Any attempts to interact with the menu results in an error with ubiquity, and it crashes: 
[image]
[image]
In that error message, it lists an identical bug on launchpad, [seen here.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1064151) It appears this could be solved by enabling `nodmraid`, however when I am at the boot option menu, I can select nothing. I suspect this is a hardware issue, since another user on launchpad has the same error with the same exact laptop. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Update: Using [this guide](https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560)) I have attempted to change the BIOS into AHCI mode with SATA, instead of RAID. However, that prevents my Windows from booting, giving an `INACCESIBLE_BOOT_DEVICE` error. Thus that seems like a dead end.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Ubuntu page for installing in UEFI mode [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI), I have disabled FastBoot and Intel Smart Response Technology in Windows. After that, the installation continued as expected.